# Expanding Polygon to Match Boundaries

Tags: postgis

I have two shapefiles. One is the [DMA](http://bl.ocks.org/simzou/6459889) and another of [states](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE/).

What I'm trying to do is "expand" a DMA boundary to match the boundary of the states, since the DMA map doesn't extend all the way. To illustrate:

This is the map of the Mid Atlantic and Midwest region states:

[image: states]

And this is the DMA for the same region:
[image: dma]

And this is the overlay between the two shapefiles:
[image: overlay]

Is there any way I can create a query that will artifically increase the size of the DMA to match the state boundaries? The reason why I need this is because I plan on going a large spatial join with coordinates and I know alot of people will not be counted for if we use the current DMA shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

I saw on you [page](http://bl.ocks.org/simzou/6459889) that you converted a shapefile to topojson. Try getting the original DMA shapefile and projecting it so that it matches the state shapefile. I looks like a projection error. Also, the DMA doesn't match up with state boundaries, so a join might give you fits. You could do something like a [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) or [clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000004000000).